# PHP namespaces and classes

Tags: php, namespaces

I have two classes, both in different namespaces. When i try to create the object from one namespace, then i get the error

```
Fatal error:  Class 'Classes\DrDatabase' not found in C:\Path\to\workspace\AplicationName\app\models\Users.model.php on line XY
```

Is there something i did not understand with php namespaces?

the two files:

```
FILE 1
namespace Classes;

class DrDatabase extends MssqlDatabase {

public function __construct() {
    parent::createLog(__CLASS__);
    parent::connect('ipaddress', 'database', 'user', 'password');
    if ($this->link) {
        $this->log->info('Connected');
    }
}
}

FILE 2
namespace Model;

use \Classes\DrDatabase;

class UsersModel implements MasterModel {
    private function get($id, $onlyEnabled) {
        $db = new DrDatabase();
        $getOnlyEnabled = 1;
        if (!$onlyEnabled)
            $getOnlyEnabled = 0;
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM table";
        $resultSet = $db->query($SQL);
        $result = array();
        while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($resultSet)) {
            $result[] = self::createUserObject($row['col1'],$row['col2']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try it with a "\" in front, like so: `$db = new \DrDatabase();`

Comment: You can only instantiate classes that are defined. In your case, the definition of `\Classes\DrDatabase` has not been loaded. Load it and you're fine. That's just what the error message tells you and it is not lying.

Comment: \Classes is a terrible name for a namespace.  It doesn't tell you anything about what it contains.

Comment: yes i know, that is just a working name, but only that one namespace has to be renamed. I'm not happy with "model" either, so i will be renaming them to something more meaningful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're using a properly configured autoloader you'll still have to include "FILE 1" for it to work correctly.

Otherwise - How would your `UserModel` know where to find the `DrDatabase` class?